# rails "undefined method" when invoking a helper method from layout view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout

I have an helper method in to get the current shopping cart in my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time

  private

  def current_cart
    if session[:cart_id]
      @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
      session[:cart_id] = nil if @current_cart.purchased_at
    end
    if session[:cart_id].nil?
      @current_cart = Cart.create!
      session[:cart_id] = @current_cart.id
    end
    @current_cart
  end

end
```

I can call the method from most of my views, but I want to use it in the views/layout/application.html.erb file, 
like this:

```
<div id="cart_menu">
    <ul>
    <li>
      <%= image_tag("cart.jpg")%>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= link_to "#{current_cart.number_of_items}", current_cart_url %>
    </li>
    <li>
          <a href="/checkout/">Checkout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But when I try that, I get an

```
undefined local variable or method `current_cart' for #<#<Class:0x2d2d834>:0x2d2b908>
```

error..

Any ideas whyis that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add  `helper_method :current_cart` to your application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :current_cart
  ...
end
```

Comment: i use already helper: all - shouldn't this include all the methods as helpers?

Comment: @frank blizzard: `helper :all` mean that you will include all methods from the all helpers from _app/helpers_ and these methods will be available in the views. But `helper_method` used to declare a controller method as a helper.

Comment: ok, thanks for clarification - changed this to the apprpriate answer as it only gets executed when necessary, unlinke the before_filter solution.

Answer (score 8):

Your example fail because you define the method `current_cart` in the ApplicationController but controller method are not accessible in the view.

There are two ways to achieve what you want :

The first way is to move the method `current_cart` in an helper.

The second way will be to set the variable `@current_cart` with a `before_filter` and use `@current_cart` in the view, see below :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time

  before_filter :set_current_cart

  private

  def set_current_cart
    if session[:cart_id]
      @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
      session[:cart_id] = nil if @current_cart.purchased_at
    end
    if session[:cart_id].nil?
      @current_cart = Cart.create!
      session[:cart_id] = @current_cart.id
    end
  end

end
```

In your view :

```
<%= link_to "#{@current_cart.number_of_items}", current_cart_url %>
```

Comment: @frank..I believe the correct answer is as @Tumtu described: add `helper_method :current_cart` in your application controller to make this method accessible to views. The method described here has a disadvantage that you have to specify where all to use this using `before_filter` in the specific controller.otherwise the filter will be executed before every action.

Answer (score 0):

Helper methods belong to the helper modules, e.g. in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

Comment: the question is how can i access my current_cart object in the application.html.erb view?

Comment: You can put your `current_cart` method as is in the helper. But in your case, it seems you'd better use the `before_filter` way the others gave.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not sure, why this works in other views, but I think, as a site-wide logic, you should define it as a before_filter for ApplicationController. If you only need it in one controller, put it there.

And it's not a "helpers". Helpers are stored in `app/helpers` and are usually used to simplify views by hiding some html inside it's methods.