# Missing devise routes helpers inside of rails engine views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-engines

I'm building a Rails engine called Engrave.

I have the engine mounted like so:

```
# Routes.rb of the host app
mount Engrave::Engine => "/engrave", :as => "engrave_engine"
```

Within this engine I have a controller called "PostsController". When I navigate to this controller to view a post like so: `/engrave/posts/1` I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_user_session_path'
```

The PostsController in the engine is inheriting from the engine controller, which is inheriting from the application controller, like so:

```
module Engrave
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
  ...
end

class Engrave::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
end
```

The new_user_session_path is being defined by devise, which I have setup like:

```
devise_for :users
```

The call to new_user_session_path is in the `layouts/application.html.erb` template file in the **host app**

I cannot figure out why this route helper isn't available in this context. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've marked StrangeDays answer as correct, because it does technically fix the problem, but if anyone has an idea of how to use an engine in this manner without requiring modification of all my layout templates, that would be awesome. I played around and managed to accomplish what I wanted by creating a full engine instead of an isolated/mountable one. I think I'm still missing something, I want to have my cake and eat it too on this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

main_app.new_user_session_path

that should work

Answer (score 8):

I've had success doing the following in the main app's application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # Can search for named routes directly in the main app, omitting
  # the "main_app." prefix
  def method_missing method, *args, &block
    if main_app_url_helper?(method)
      main_app.send(method, *args)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to?(method)
    main_app_url_helper?(method) or super
  end

 private

  def main_app_url_helper?(method)
    (method.to_s.end_with?('_path') or method.to_s.end_with?('_url')) and
      main_app.respond_to?(method)
  end
end
```

I've used this in mountable engines, so you do not have to sacrifice those features.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328203/rails-undefined-method-when-invoking-a-helper-method-from-layout-view#comment7401450_6328487), I include all helpers found in application_helpers.rb by stating `helper "manager/application"` inside the controller (if 'manager' is the current namespace of your mountable engine. Just use 'application' if you are calling this from a standard application).