# ApplicationHelper methods not available in Devise Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've a legacy Rails 3.2 app in which I'm using Devise for authentication. Previously, Devise had been using the default application layout for it's SessionController, and all the app's controllers explicitly declared `layout "public"`. I decided to change the public layout to `application.haml`, and the previous application layout to `devise.haml`. To ensure that `Devise::SessionsController` uses the correct layout, I added this to my `application.rb` file:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.layout "devise"
end
```

When I add this however, my integration tests start failing because they can't access a view helper defined in ApplicationHelper. Why does changing the layout for the controller in this fashion preclude the usage of ApplicationHelper methods and how can I remedy this?

Comment: Having the same problem... Did you figure this out?

Comment: Same problem here too.

Answer (score 2):

Include `ApplicationHelper` to your controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  include ApplicationHelper
  def new
    super do |resource|
      resource.type = your_helper_method
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Working off of [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328203/rails-undefined-method-when-invoking-a-helper-method-from-layout-view#comment7401450_6328487), I include all helpers found in application_helpers.rb by stating `helper "manager/application"` inside the controller in question (if 'manager' is the current namespace of your mountable engine that mounts devise. Just use 'application' if you are calling this from a standard application).

Example of SessionsController

```
require_dependency "manager/application_controller"

module Manager
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
        # Without this line I get errors like 'undefined method link_to'
        helper "manager/application"
        layout "manager/application"

        def create
            resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
            sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
        end

        def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
            scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
            resource ||= resource_or_scope
            sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
            return render :json => {:success => true}
        end

        def failure
            return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
        end
    end
end
```